# Select row by array contains check

Tags: java, sql, arrays, select, hsqldb

I have a table like

```sql
CREATE TABLE table(
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    array INTEGER ARRAY NOT NULL
);
```

For example if I have the rows

```
name: test, array: [1, 2, 3]
name: test2, array: [663, 332, 334]
```

How can I select the row which contains 332 in `array`? The array can be of any length but never null.

Unfortunately there isn't much documentation on HSQLDB arrays.. I'm using version 2.5.1 with Java JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. There was an exception caused by a previous method call which prevented the actual exception from throwing.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 332 IN ( UNNEST(array) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 332 IN UNNEST([663, 332, 334]) AS contains_value;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: This is incorrect. The question was to use the array column as the array to check contains for, the question is already solved and that will throw a syntax error.